# Can we access Computer management through Windows Recovery Environment's cmd?

Tags: windows, operating-system

I got into a situation where I couldn't change myself back into admin after I had switched my account type to user. Administrator account was also disabled.

I have already tried compmgmt.msc in windows recovery environment's cmd, so I was wondering if there were other solutions to accessing computer management in windows recovery environment.